# Having trouble triggering a function on slide in JQuery UI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I'm building a value-lookup "calculator" and using jQuery UI - I have tried several methods, but my experience with jQuery and creating functions in it is somewhat limited - I am able to easily get the value of the slider and perform the value lookups at the beginning of the page load, but any time I insert anything that would get the value and do the lookup function again after load makes the slider break - Any ideas?  here's my code below, and a fiddle to play with (https://jsfiddle.net/8hhyjdbm/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 20000,
      max: 300000,
      value: 20000,
      step:5000,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        $( "#financed" ).html( document.getElementById('amount').value);
        getme();
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });


$(function(){
var refival = function(Insured, GSR, REFI, Builder, Home_Owner, Const_Loan, Subdivider, Stand_Alone, Simul_Lender, Combo) {
    this.Insured = Insured;
    this.GSR = GSR;
    this.REFI = REFI;
    this.Builder = Builder;
    this.Home_Owner = Home_Owner;
    this.Const_Loan = Const_Loan;
    this.Subdivider = Subdivider;
    this.Stand_Alone = Stand_Alone;
    this.Simul_Lender = Simul_Lender;
    this.Combo = Combo;
};


var refivals = [
new refival("20000","300","200","220","220","220","220","405","255","243"),
new refival("25000","322","200","220","220","220","220","435","263","250"),
new refival("30000","344","200","220","220","220","220","465","271","258"),
    ];


var utils = {};
utils.inArray = function(searchFor, property) {
    var retVal = -1;
    var self = this;
    for(var index=0; index < self.length; index++){
        var item = self[index];
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (item[property].toLowerCase() === searchFor.toLowerCase()) {
                retVal = index;
                return retVal;
            }
        }
    };
    return retVal;
};

Array.prototype.inArray = utils.inArray;

var i = refivals.inArray(document.getElementById('amount').value, "Insured");
$('#GSR').text(refivals[i].GSR);
$('#REFI').text(refivals[i].REFI);
$('#Builder').text(refivals[i].Builder);
$('#Const_Loan').text(refivals[i].Const_Loan);
$('#Subdivider').text(refivals[i].Subdivider);
$('#Stand_Alone').text(refivals[i].Builder);
$('#Simul_Lender').text(refivals[i].Const_Loan);
$('#Combo').text(refivals[i].Subdivider);

function getme() {
    var i = refivals.inArray(document.getElementById('amount').value, "Insured");
    $('#GSR').text(refivals[i].GSR);
    $('#REFI').text(refivals[i].REFI);
    $('#Builder').text(refivals[i].Builder);
    $('#Const_Loan').text(refivals[i].Const_Loan);
    $('#Subdivider').text(refivals[i].Subdivider);
    $('#Stand_Alone').text(refivals[i].Builder);
    $('#Simul_Lender').text(refivals[i].Const_Loan);
    $('#Combo').text(refivals[i].Subdivider);
}

});
</script>
<p>
<label for="amount">Insured Amount:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>
<hr>
<div>GSR:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="GSR"></span>
    <br>REFI:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="REFI"></span>
    <br>Builder:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="Builder"></span>
    <br>Const_Loan:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="Const_Loan"></span>
    <br>Subdivider:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="Subdivider"></span>
    <br>Stand_Alone:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="Stand_Alone"></span>
    <br>Simul_Lender:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="Simul_Lender"></span>
    <br>Combo:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="Combo"></span>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to see this break in the fiddle?

Comment: I just added the line that breaks it: line 15, where I call the function "getme()" - I'm attempting to update the values of the spans below when the slider slides...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically your issue is how you defined things. You wrapped things in two different ready shorthand functions which made them unavailable to one another because of function scope. So when you tried to call `getme` from slider slide event it couldn't find `getme`. Let me know if this is working as you want now. I also had to add an if statement in `getme` to handle values that were not defined. I assume later you will have more `revivals` because it stops changing values once you go over 30000. Also had to change some lines where you set values because I don't think you had the correct properties being used.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/8hhyjdbm/5/

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-range-max").slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 20000,
        max: 300000,
        value: 20000,
        step: 5000,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            getme();
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val($("#slider-range-max").slider("value"));

    var i = refivals.inArray(document.getElementById('amount').value, "Insured");
    $('#GSR').text(refivals[i].GSR);
    $('#REFI').text(refivals[i].REFI);
    $('#Builder').text(refivals[i].Builder);
    $('#Const_Loan').text(refivals[i].Const_Loan);
    $('#Subdivider').text(refivals[i].Subdivider);
    $('#Stand_Alone').text(refivals[i].Stand_Alone);
    $('#Simul_Lender').text(refivals[i].Simul_Lender);
    $('#Combo').text(refivals[i].Combo);
});

var refival = function (Insured, GSR, REFI, Builder, Home_Owner, Const_Loan, Subdivider, Stand_Alone, Simul_Lender, Combo) {
    this.Insured = Insured;
    this.GSR = GSR;
    this.REFI = REFI;
    this.Builder = Builder;
    this.Home_Owner = Home_Owner;
    this.Const_Loan = Const_Loan;
    this.Subdivider = Subdivider;
    this.Stand_Alone = Stand_Alone;
    this.Simul_Lender = Simul_Lender;
    this.Combo = Combo;
};


var refivals = [
new refival("20000", "300", "200", "220", "220", "220", "220", "405", "255", "243"),
new refival("25000", "322", "200", "220", "220", "220", "220", "435", "263", "250"),
new refival("30000", "344", "200", "220", "220", "220", "220", "465", "271", "258"), ];


var utils = {};
utils.inArray = function (searchFor, property) {
    var retVal = -1;
    var self = this;
    for (var index = 0; index < self.length; index++) {
        var item = self[index];
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (item[property].toLowerCase() == searchFor.toLowerCase()) {
                retVal = index;
                return retVal;
            }
        }
    };
    return retVal;
};

Array.prototype.inArray = utils.inArray;

function getme() {
    var i = refivals.inArray(document.getElementById('amount').value, "Insured");
    if (typeof i == 'undefined' || !refivals[i]) {
        return;
    }
    $('#GSR').text(refivals[i].GSR);
    $('#REFI').text(refivals[i].REFI);
    $('#Builder').text(refivals[i].Builder);
    $('#Const_Loan').text(refivals[i].Const_Loan);
    $('#Subdivider').text(refivals[i].Subdivider);
    $('#Stand_Alone').text(refivals[i].Stand_Alone);
    $('#Simul_Lender').text(refivals[i].Simul_Lender);
    $('#Combo').text(refivals[i].Combo);
}
```

Comment: No problem!! Happy to help!